# How to pass a value of page to other page without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jsp

The page passed on the infoCheck.php for the POST.

First of all, I'm going to move on as follows.

```
<form id="theForm" method = "POST" action = "infoCheck.php"
   <input type = "hidden" name = "name" value = "100">
   <input type = "submit" value = "Input">
</form>
```

However, before submit, only the value corresponding to the name must be sent as soon as the page opens. There must be away. Even if I searched, I could only see how to use submit...
What should I do?

Comment: So, you wanna send the value of `name` field to `infoCheck.php` when this page opens ? Also, typo line 2, you wrote `hdden` instead of `hidden`.

Comment: sorry, i dont really understand the description of yours.. regarding *value of page to other page* you might can use [`$_SESSION`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) if the value is sent to the php on the previous page..

Answer (score 4):

Try this if you use jQuery:

HTML

```
<form id="theForm" method="POST" action="infoCheck.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="100">
  <input type="submit" value="Input">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#theForm").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to submit the form as soon as the page loads. Here's what you can do using JS (as per the tags from your question):

### HTML

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="infoCheck.php">
  <input type="hdden" name="name" value="100">
  <input type="submit" value="Input">
</form>
```

Note the added `id="myForm"`.

### Javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this On window load submit your form.

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['form_name'].submit();
}
```

You can also use SESSION variable to use data globally.

I recommend you to use PDO to prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Here is PDO example with prepared statement:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) 
    VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

    // insert a row
    $firstname = "John";
    $lastname = "Doe";
    $email = "john@example.com";
    $stmt->execute();

    // insert another row
    $firstname = "Mary";
    $lastname = "Moe";
    $email = "mary@example.com";
    $stmt->execute();

    // insert another row
    $firstname = "Julie";
    $lastname = "Dooley";
    $email = "julie@example.com";
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding of your question, I will explain it to you. Instead of using submit, you can use the code below.

```
<script>
jQuery('form').submit();
</script>
```

I think it can pass the "name" to infoCheck.php